# How to use the Drupal "Node Invite" module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I cannot find any documentation for the Drupal [Node Invite](http://drupal.org/project/node_invite) module. As somewhat of a beginner with Drupal, the usage suggestion "The module creates entries in $node->links" means close to nothing to me, and the video tour link on the module's main page (http://www.adevbox.com/files/2008-06-25_1703.swf) is broken.

Following the suggestion from the Drupal forums, I have created a new issue for this problem, but the activity around the module does not seem to be very high, so I'm not holding my breath.

Is there some documentation available somewhere else? I have no idea how to use this module without some docs or tutorials. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$node->links is the variable that creates various links like **add a comment** , **add to favorites** and so on. You can see this links in the node display after the other details.

So Node invite will create a link like **Share this node with your friends**

Don't forget to check out the settings for the module, which will help you in changing the default text.

However I should accept that the usage message is not very user friendly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I at least know where to start looking now :-)